Why does DataTables use div instead of table tags for advanced configurations?
I'm trying to build a DataTable from scratch using ReactJS.
I noticed that in some advanced examples and configurations, the plugin uses <div> elements rather than traditional <table> tags.
Here is a sample of the code I'm referring to:
<div id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!-- DataTable is initialized here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Could someone explain why DataTables uses  elements in these cases? What are the benefits of this approach compared to using standard  elements?

col-sm-12  This convention is often used for responsive layouts,.  <table> is not a responsive element.   If your not into responsive table layouts, then you can still use <table>..  So the benefits are of course responsive layout.   In theory you can even hack <table> to be responsive, but it's sometimes not very pretty and as flexible.. :)

What I understand from you is all the advanced datatable using div tag rather than table tag for styling or responsive purpose? Or is there any other reason, what I provide is just example
